# Changing values in a yaml file from a csv file

Tags: python, yaml

I have a script that extract certains values in a csv file, to incorporate them in severals yalm file to a certain location in those files.

```
import ruamel.yaml
from csv import reader
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True

with open('config.yaml') as yml:
    doc = yaml.load(yml)

with open('params.csv') as f:
    for i, data in enumerate(reader(f)):
        doc['components']['star']['init'][0]['values']['logg'] = data[4]
        filename = data[1].split(".")[0] 
        with open(f'{filename}.yaml', 'w') as out:
            yaml.dump(doc, out)
        #break
```

As you can see, it takes the values in a column of the csv file, one by one, change this value (logg) in the reference yaml file and save it, and it does this for each value so I end up with several yaml files.

The issue is, that when the value is replaced, instead of getting for example:

```
logg: 4.5
```

I get:

```
logg: '4.5'
```

Would you have an idea to make it without having the `''`, because I can not make it work with this ?
Thanks

Comment: The value is most likely treated as a string. Try casting `data[4]` to float: `float(data[4])`...?

Comment: Well, indeed, this was simple ! Thanks